# Get the order in which methods are called in django class based views

Tags: ajax, django, methods, django-class-based-views

I've been thinking of this for a long time. I know `__mro__` of class will return the inheritance hierarchy. But how can I get the order in which funtions are called in class?

Below is the scenario that I am going through. I have to implement `pagination in ListView` using ajax. I came to a conclusion that  `render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs)` is the last method called just before returning the template. If I inspect `content_type` I can return template or a json response if the url is called using ajax. I should have done this with `django-rest-framework` with much less effort, but the requirement clearly states that web application and api should be two separate files. So my render_to_response looks like below.

```
def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
    
    response_kwargs.setdefault('content_type', self.content_type)
    if self.request.content_type == 'application/json':
        return json.loads(myJsonResponse)
    else:
        return self.response_class(
            request=self.request,
            template=self.get_template_names(),
            context=context,
            using=self.template_engine,
            **response_kwargs
        )
```

I have been referring to [ccbv](http://ccbv.co.uk/) for these kind of stuff.

It should be very helpful if a way devised to get the order in which functions are called in django class based views since I love `dry coding` and I can make use of this idea everywhere in django cbv when needed.

TIA

Comment: You can use `return super(MyView, self).render_to_response(context, **response_kwargs)` in the `else` block to make your method more DRY.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Alasdair. I already voted your comment up :)